# Ruby 1.8.7 ordering of a hash with JSON.parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I've been having trouble figuring this out so I figured i'd ask here. I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and RoR 1.2.6. I have my controller rendering this JSON:

```
{
  "form_id": "1",
  "form_structure": {
    "3": {
        "answer_required": "undefined",
        "title": "This is a radio group, right?",
        "cssClass": "radio",
        "values": {
            "4": {
                "value": "Yes",
                "baseline": "undefined"
            },
            "5": {
                "value": "No",
                "baseline": "undefined"
            },
            "7": {
                "value": "Maybe",
                "baseline": "undefined"
            },
            "20": {
                "value": "Test",
                "baseline": "undefined"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the options under "values" are ordered by the ID from the table. Looks perfect in JSON. When I use `JSON.parse` on it, everything under "values" get's all out of whack and it returns this:

```
{
  "form_id"=>"1",
  "form_structure"=>{
    "3"=>{
        "title"=>"This is a radio group, right?",
        "cssClass"=>"radio",
        "answer_required"=>"undefined",
        "values"=>{
            "7"=>{
                "baseline"=>"undefined",
                "value"=>"Maybe"
            },
            "20"=>{
                "baseline"=>"undefined",
                "value"=>"Test"
            },
            "4"=>{
                "baseline"=>"undefined",
                "value"=>"Yes"
            },
            "5"=>{
                "baseline"=>"undefined",
                "value"=>"No"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This code is used in a formbuilder that I'm making, and it wouldn't really be nice if the form elements that a person builds don't show up in the correct order that they built them in. Anyone have insights on how I can keep the ordering or reorder them as I output or right before then?

Comment: There's no Ruby version 1.8.9…

Comment: `Hash` is not ordered in 1.8.7, can you change your `JSON` so it looks like `{"values" => [[7, {"baseline" => ...}], [20, ...`? It will be a good thing anyway, ordering hash is a tricky business.

Comment: hash by definition has no order. Deal with it and change it to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
form["form_structure"]["3"]["values"] = 
form["form_structure"]["3"]["values"].sort {
        |a,b| a[0].to_i <=> b[0].to_i
 }
```

This will sort the hash based on the integer value of the keys in the values hash and put the sorted hash back in the larger hash.

If you need to keep it all still hashes use this:

```
 val = {}
 val = form["form_structure"]["3"]["values"].sort { 
      |a,b| a[0].to_i <=> b[0].to_i }
 ind = []
 val.each { |v| ind += [v[0]] }
 val = {}
 ind.each { |k| val[k] = form["form_structure"]["3"]["values"][k] }
 form["form_structure"]["3"]["values"] = val
```

Comment: Err, actually this converts the Hash at the key `values` to a sorted Array. Hash order is never guaranteed in Ruby 1.8

Comment: Well you cannot access an array in the same way you do a hash, so the behavior is entirely different.

Comment: Now it an ordered hash of hashes. Yes in theory you can't count on the order but in real life you can for a moment and that is all he really needs.

Comment: Thanks, the first option worked the best, I just edited my helper method that generated the html.

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade to 1.9.x ruby version to get the hash order